# Having a dynamic loop of timers

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to write a tool to ping certain things every `x` mins. I've got the following code creating my threads and the pinging is fine, it's just I can't work out how to dynamically make a timer in my thread each time. The data is a table such as:

```
Id  Name        URL                     Time    Active
1   All good    http://httpstat.us/200  5000    1
2   404         http://httpstat.us/404  2000    1
```

The code I have is as follows: (i've not put the variables in from the loop yet)

```
public void SetupTimers()
{
    DB db = new DB();
    DataTable dtLinks = new DataTable();
    dtLinks = db.GetDataTable(String.Format("SELECT Id, Name, URL, Time, Active FROM Shed WHERE Active = 1"));
    foreach (DataRow row in dtLinks.Rows)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => SetupShed(1, "WILLBURL", "WILLBENAME"));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

And

```
static void SetupShed(Int32 Time, String URL, String Name)
{
   /* Heres where I will do the actual ping 
      but I need to setup a timer to loop every x seconds? 
      It's a contiunous check so it'll have to keep looping over. 
      I've redacted the actual ping for this example
   */
}
```

Comment: You can use Quartz.net library. It was specifically designed for scheduling. Or checkout this tutorial http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html

Comment: Most of the time it is WAY better to either use some existing tool for that OR if you want to do it yourself to have ONE single mainthread that is running ONE timer and then starts the threads accordingly. The reason behind this is simple. Each StopWatch for example has its own thread. Thus doubling your number of threads. If you use a different method you would have to let the timers check or sleep for the aforementioned time which can lead to complex statements or problems if you want to kill them preliminarily again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Timer` class. You don't actually need to create your own threads.
The timer class does that for you behind the scenes.

```
public void SetupTimers()
{
    DB db = new DB();
    DataTable dtLinks = new DataTable();
    dtLinks = db.GetDataTable(String.Format("SELECT Id, Name, URL, Time, Active FROM Shed WHERE Active = 1"));
    foreach (DataRow row in dtLinks.Rows)
    {
        SetupShed(1, "WILLBURL", "WILLBENAME");
    }
}


static void SetupShed(double ms, String url, String name)
{
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(ms);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Ping(url, name);
        timer.Start();
}

static void Ping(String url, String name)
{
    //do you pinging
}
```

Comment: Does the auto reset make it so taht it is called  again after the same amount of time? (if I understand the OP correctly he wants to have that as sort of a endless loop)

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what `AutoReset` does.

Comment: And even stopable easily. If the OP does not want to raise the timer events again he could just return the timer and add it to a list and then stop all timers in that list for example. Have to say I like that approach! (+1)

Comment: Ah this is perfect. Can you elaborate on the stopping? Is the UI updatable whilst running a thread like this? Thank you so much

Comment: I worked out the list (Thanks @Thomas) - Just the UI update i've not got yet, normally I just do this.Invoke but this isnt available for some reason

Answer (score 0):

One possible method would be to let the thread sleep until you want it to run. BUT this CAN cause some undesired effects like lots of processes that do absolutely......nothing. Additionally if you want to end them preliminarily......it won't work without quite a lot of additional checks (for example if you want it to end now it is not good if it ends in 5000 milliseconds....so you would need to check every 10-20 milliseconds, ....).

Taking your initial approach (Be aware though that Time is given in milliseconds here. If you want to have it in seconds then you need to use: Thread.Sleep(Time*1000)):

```
static void SetupShed(Int32 Time, String URL, String Name)
{
   /* Heres where I will do the actual ping 
      but I need to setup a timer to loop every x seconds? 
      It's a contiunous check so it'll have to keep looping over. 
      I've redacted the actual ping for this example
   */

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(Time);
        //.....Do my stuff and then loop again.
    }
}
```